# How to check if a set of n integer jumps forms an n-length cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, modular-arithmetic

Problem asks to check if a set of n integers corresponds to cycle of size n.

Each integer $a_i$, represents a circular jump to the right by $a_i$ indices. (Starting from index j = 0, each step we move to $(j + a_j) \text{ mod } n, (j + a_j) + a_{j + a_j} \text { mod n}, $ and so on and so forth.)

E.g. [2, 3, 1, -4, -4, 2] = true. (Simulating the jumps from index 0: 0, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4) (Permutation of 0 to n-1)

Is there a mathematical condition I can check here? (Without doing the simulation?)

I tried checking for the sum (necessary, but not sufficient)

Maybe partial sums?

For the following example it doesn't work:

[1, 2, 3, 2] = false

Comment: Please leave a comment if you downvote so that I understand what is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: It seems a strange definition of cycle.  More common would be addition of a constant amount modulo something.  You should make the definition clear, not hidden in a parenthetic remark.  I would be surprised if there is anything simpler than just checking the definition.  You need to look at the whole set of jumps to see if they are what you want.

Comment: Added. Yes, I will check by the definition as it's relatively easy to simulate in Python /  C++.